# Enable header for only specific screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Ok, this is a simple scenario. Say I've a `StackNavigator` with 100 screens. 2 of them need the header and 98 of them need not to have header. So writing same header configuration for 98 screen is doesn't sound like a good approach to me, and what i did is, disabled the header by setting `header : null` in global config like this

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({

    ScreenOne: ScreenOne,
    ScreenTwo: ScreenTwo,
    ... : ... ,
    ScreenHundred : ScreenHundred
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'ScreenOne',
        navigationOptions: {
        header: null
    },
});
```

and tried to enable the `header` from within the screen class.

```
class ScreenOne extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'ScreenOne',
  };

  /* render function, etc */
}
```

but that doesn't work. How do i fix this problem ? **Is there any built-in pattern like approach** where I'd say `enable header for 2 screens only, and disable it for remaining screens` ?

Edit:

One solution is to create a new class `class HeaderLessComponent extends Component` , which will override the `navigationProps` with `header : null`, and all 98 screens will extend the `HeaderLessComponent`.

Comment: Remove navigation option from main stack navigator and navigationOptions:{header: null} in screens where you don't want the header

Comment: I knw it'd work. but **writing same header configuration for 98 screen is not a good approach**, is there any alternative ?

Comment: then I suggest  to define custom header in those screens navigationOptions:{header:<Component/>}

Comment: you have to overwrite header configuration in navigationOptions of those screen  beacuse by default it is taking null.

Comment: Yeah, It'd work also. but i need to know if there's any built-in pattern like approach.

Comment: Another solution would be create another class `class HeaderLessComponent extends Component` , which by default overrides the navigationProps and disable the header. and all 98 screens will be extending  the `HeaderLessComponent`. It'd also work right ?

Comment: yup that will also work